# return multiple column from sub query and insert into new table

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I have a query for insert  into table using sub query prob is that in sub query there
is 2 columns and with where condition and group by clause.

sub query is running well can any one help me plz

Query : Account_name is type text

```
insert into trial_bal (Account_name,Debit) values (

select convert(text,convert(varchar(max),Accounts)),SUM(ISNULL( Debit,0))-SUM( ISNULL(Credit,0)) 

from general

where Acount_Type='Assets'
group by convert(varchar(max),Accounts)
);
```

Comment: Please read the mysql documentation. You don't use `VALUES` when you're using a `SELECT` statement to get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `INSERT INTO ..VALUES` you should use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT..FROM` to return the values from the select statement:

```
insert into trial_bal (Account_name,Debit)
select convert(text,convert(varchar(max),Accounts)),
  SUM(ISNULL( Debit,0))-SUM( ISNULL(Credit,0))
from general
where Acount_Type='Assets' 
group by convert(varchar(max),Accounts)
```